# Spark Memory allocation in YARN for apache zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-zeppelin

I run Spark through Zeppelin in a YARN cluster. When I see my YARN web ui I see that 
Zeppelin uses 1 container, 1 core and 1g of memory. So go to my interpreter settings and I change them to:

```
spark.cores.max 8 
spark.executor.memory 8g
```

and I restart the interpreter but my memory allocation stays the same:
[image]

I event tried to add to interpreter property args to:

```
args --driver-memory 8G --executor-memory 8G --executor-cores 8
```

but no change either.

Appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Have you specified `"yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator":"org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator"` in `capacity-scheduler.xml`?

Comment: Turn out that Zeppelin does not request the memory from YARN until it is necessary. I will later answer this question or delete this post.

Answer (score 1):

### Two Options

1. edit `$ZEPPELIN_HOME/conf/zeppelin-env.sh`, add `export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS="--num-executors 10 --driver-memory 8g --executor-memory 10g --executor-cores 4 "`.

   - if you don't have zeppelin-env.sh, please copy and rename `zeppelin-env.sh.template` to `zeppelin-env.sh`.
2. edit `$SPARK_CONF_DIR/spark-defaults.conf` and modify what you want to add.

After that, restart your server.

Comment: As @zjffdu said, zeppelin 0.8.0 do fix that bugs.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug of zeppelin 0.7.x, 0.8.0 has fixed this issue.